# typeahead error Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

typeahead.min.js 0.9.3

I get an error:

My the data of the searchbox is called from the backend to keep the search data always upd to date:

```
$('#searchbox').typeahead({
    limit: 10,
    minLength: 2,
    remote: function(query, process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/typeahead',
            type: "GET",
            data: {'s': $('#searchbox').val() },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                return process(result.names);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    },
    updater: function(item) {
        var values = $('#searchbox').data('values');
        alert(values);
        for (var index in values) {
            if (values[index].name == item) {
                location.href = values[index].href;
                break;
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
});
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined typeahead.min.js:347
utils.mixin.get typeahead.min.js:347
x.isFunction.i jquery.js:4
utils.mixin.getSuggestions typeahead.min.js:530
x.isFunction.i jquery.js:4
(anonymous function) typeahead.min.js:995
x.extend.each jquery.js:4
utils.mixin._getSuggestions typeahead.min.js:994
x.isFunction.i jquery.js:4
EventTarget.trigger typeahead.min.js:162
x.isFunction.i jquery.js:4
utils.mixin._compareQueryToInputValue typeahead.min.js:609
x.isFunction.i jquery.js:4
x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5
y.handle
```

Now I really do not know what to change or where the error is. Anybody an idea?

Comment: What is getting logged out for your results?

Comment: the error comes instantly when I press a key (letter)

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen syntax for the remote option like that.  The [docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#remote) call for it to be a URL, which is what I've always used.  So something like this for your request:

```
remote: '/typeahead?s=%QUERY',
```

I've also never seen an `updater` option either, so I'm not sure if that is going to work as you intend.